# How to link domains hosted on one hosting account

Tags: seo, links, nofollow, negative-seo

I have several different domains hosted on one hosting account and some of these domains are linked together not because I am trying to influence page rank but because they contain related content. However, recently I learned that this creates some thing called private blog network of PBN which Google dislikes.

Is there a way to avoid this without upsetting Google and does changing the links to no-follow links solve this problem?

Comment: If these linked sites "contain related content" and it makes sense to your users to link between them then this really shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Be natural, do what a reasonable webmaster would do, and try not to get too carried away.

Answer (score 1):

hellno's

- don't link site-wide (from header, footer, sidebar, navbar)
- don't link with keyword optimized link anchors

damnyes's

- do link from with textual content (articles)
- if link with keyword optimized anchors, nofollow such links
- buy and setup for each site an own dedicated IP-address (they aren't expensive)

Answer (score 0):

You can purchase separate IP addresses assigned to each domain name from Your hosting company.

Comment: The system flagged this as a low quality post because of it's length. Can you add more detail to help the OP? For example, how this will effect the OP's concern and whether there are any other steps that can help.